# Bayesian Information Criterion Formula Proof

Tags: regression, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, arima, bic

while I was digging arima model I saw that BIC value is given as $k*log(n)-2*log(L)$ where $L$ is the maximized value of likelihood function whereas $k$ is number of parameters. I wonder how it is derived. Could you help me with the proof?

Regards;

Comment: proof for what?

Comment: Why BIC value has a formula like that? Does it have any derivation?

Comment: Here it is with detailed explanations: https://faculty.ucmerced.edu/hbhat/BICderivation.pdf